# Azure GPU intensive tasks best solution

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, gpu, azure-web-app-service

Where currently working on some GPU intensive tasks. We have running a Azure App Service for our main application, but cant find out what kind of GPU is running on it.

Also looked into Azure Functions or running a separate VM, but we would like to stay with the Azure App Service for our main application.

What would be the best solution to run GPU intensive task on Azure?

Comment: App Services does not support running GPUs. You will need to switch to another service such as Azure Batch, Databricks, ACI or Azure Machine Learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for Machine Learning tasks using [Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/) or [HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/) services, as I known, there are two services which be suitable for GPU intensive tasks.

1. Azure [Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/), please see the offical document [`Use RDMA or GPU instances in Batch pools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-pool-compute-intensive-sizes)
2. The GPU series Virtual Machine for Windows or Linux, such as `NC-series`, `NC-series Promo`, `NCsv2-series`, `NCsv3-series`, `NV-series`, `NV-series Promo`, `NVv3-series`, `NVv4-series`, `NDs-series` and `NDv2 series` from the pricing page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/, as the figure below.

   [image]

If your GPU intensive tasks are not heavy and not require the Nvidia GPU, I think Azure Functions and App Services based on Linux docker container also can be used for tasks using OpenGL.

Comment: can we have GPU compute in an azure web app for containers/app service?

Answer (score 0):

Azure [Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/configure-azure-container-instances/?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Marketplace) are another option and offer [auto scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/scale-app?pivots=azure-portal)